# Fetch tiles in a pattern

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I have a large tile grid from where I want to select a bunch of tiles in a specific area. The selection of the tiles is going to start from the black tile.

[image]

I made a picture to illustrate what tiles I want. The only thing I have is the center tile. As you can see on the picture the distance from the center and to the border tiles are manhattan distance.

This is a explaination of what the algorithm will need. A center tile and a distance.

```
std::vector<Tile*> getTilesInArea(Tile *centerTile, int distance)
{
    // Do calculation and return a vector with the wanted tiles
}
```

NOTE. The distance are in tiles. As you can see on the image, the distance is 10 (10 tiles in each direction from the center tile).

Thank you people.

Comment: If you have pseudo code to be fixed remove the c++ tag, otherwise show a particular problem. _'Gimme the codez plz'_ type questions are off topic anyway ...

Comment: I just wanted to further show what I meant by stating that the only things needed it a center tile and a distance. Also I don't just want the code.. I want to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the each tile has pointers to it's neighbors, up, down, right, left, here's a basic idea in pseudo code.

```
getTilesInArea(centerTile, distance):
    returnVector <- {}
    l = centerTile
    r = centerTile
    for (i = 0; i < distance; i++) 
        l = l.left
        r = r.right

        traverseUpDown(returnVector, l, distance-i)
        traverseUpDown(returnVector, r, distance-i)

    return returnVector



traverseUpDown(vector, tile, count):

    vector.add(tile)
    u = tile
    d = tile

    for (i=0; i<count; i++)
        u = u.up
        d = d.down
        vector.add(u)
        vector.add(d)
```

Comment: Sry, I don't know what <- means.
is for i <- 0 to distance do: the same as for(int i = 0; i < distance; i++)

Comment: It's just assignment. Yes the for loops are equivalent.

Comment: I've edited the solution to give a more familiar syntax.